# Weird thing hapening while setting and getting array in swift4

Tags: ios, realm, swift4

I am using a class LocalSubject.swift which i store in a RealmDB.

```
class LocalSubject: Object{

    @objc dynamic var subjectName: String?
    private var modules: [Module] = [Module]()
    @objc dynamic var moduleArrayJSON: String? = nil

    public func addModule(module: Module){
        modules.append(module)
    }

    public func setModules(modules: [Module]){
        self.modules = modules
        print("LocalSubject.swift > setModules() > " + String(describing: modules.count) + " > " + String(describing: self.modules.count))
  }

    public func getModules()-> [Module]{
         print("LocalSubject.swift > getModules() > " + String(describing: modules.count) + " > " + String(describing: self.modules.count))
        return modules.sorted(by: { $0.displayOrder! < $1.displayOrder!})
    }
}
```

I store the class in DB by converting "modules" array to json & back.
In below function, "modules" is computed correctly with count = 3, then i set it in "maths" object of LocalSubject. Now when i try to get the "modules" from "maths", i am always getting an empty array.

```
   public func createModuleArrayFromJSONInSubjects(){
            let modules = getModuleArrayFromJSON(moduleArrayJSON: (maths?.moduleArrayJSON)!)
            for module in modules{
                print("-> " + module.title!)
            }
            maths?.setModules(modules: modules)
            for module in (maths?.getModules())!{
                print("---> " + module.title!)
            }
  }
```

I am unable to figure this out, it seems weird.
Am i missing something?

Comment: What is `Module` type - is this also a Realm object? And is the `maths` object managed by Realm (i.e. stored in a Realm)?

Answer (score 1):

Realm objects do not support array types, instead you should use the Realm type `List` to maintain references to other Realm objects. If `Module` is not a Realm object subclass, you can't store a reference to it. See here: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#models

So there are two options:

1. Either change the `modules` property to be a `List` and maintain the `Module` objects in Realm too, or
2. Do you need to store the `modules` property if you are storing the JSON? You could continue to store the JSON string only, and make `modules` a computed property (for which you'd need a `getter`, and you can choose whether to make a `setter` or not).

You'll have to choose the way forward depending on your use cases.

Comment: Thanks for the direction. I chose option 2 and things worked out for me.